# JavaScript складывание чисел с h1

Tags: javascript, числа

У меня есть h1 с id outputGPA, при нажатии на кнопку выводится в этот h1 текст с кнопки и '+'

```
outputGPA.innerHTML += e.target.innerText + '+';
```

В h1 (outputGPA) выводятся числа с кнопок, например: "10+3+8+1+10", как сложить эти числа?

Буду благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```js
const nums = "10+3+8+1+10";

const numSum = nums.split('+').reduce(
  (sum, num) => sum + Number(num),
  0
);

console.log(numSum);
```

Comment: спасибо большое)